Mean of a random variable in stochastic process.
I'm reading the book "Random Data: Analysis and Measurement Procedures" of "Julius S. Bendat" and "Allan G. Piersol". In this book, a stochastic process is denoted by a ensemble functions $\{ X_k (t) \}$ where each $X_i$ ($i = \overline{1,k}$) is a sample function measured over time. The mean value at arbitrary fixed $t$ is defined as: $$\mu_x (t) = E[x_k(t)]$$
Then if I want to calculate the mean at time $t$ of a stochastic process with  $\{ x_k (t) \} = \{X cos[2 \pi f_0 t + \theta] \}$ where $\theta$ follows a Uniform distribution with $P(\theta) = 1/{2\pi}$, I will have to find the distribution of $X(t)$ from the distribution of $\theta$ and calculate the mean using the definition, but the approach in the book suggest using $X(t)$ as a function $g(\theta)$ then use $E[g(x)] = \int_{-\infty}^\infty g(x)f(x)dx$ to calculate $\mu_x$:
$$
\begin{equation*}
\mu_x = E(Xcos(2 \pi f_0 t + \theta) \\
= Xcos(2 \pi f_0t)E(cos \theta) - Xsin(2 \pi f_0t)E(sin \theta) =0
\end{equation*}
$$
The book calculate autocorrelation function instead of the example I give above but it use the same approach addressed.
I want to know what is the correct way to do this, if I have any misunderstanding about this part, I hope you can explain this knowledge to me. Any help is much appreciated.
